# aws ssm automation document with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-ssm

I used SSM Terraform module to create windows maintenance, I have created a task on one of this windows maintenance.

I have created a json file what it will help me to create a new ssm document.
The creations of the SSM document works fine, the document needs security *id and other values, I have tried to use **TempleateFile** so I can pass ID-*SG id to the document, but it does not work, the windows maintenance fails with error ***“The supplied parameters for invoking the specified Automation document are incorrect.”***
I have tried without local, just the resource but still not working.

I am not sure how to pass the SecurityGroupID to the document.

```
resource "aws_ssm_document" "t-document" {
  name          = "SGDocument"
  document_type = "Automation"
  document_format = "JSON"

  content    = templatefile("${path.module}/internet-SG.json.tpl",
    {
      SecurityGroupId      = local.SecurityGroupId 
      AutomationAssumeRole = local.AutomationAssumeRole
       
    })
}
```

json

```
{
  "schemaVersion": "0.3",
  "parameters": {
    "SecurityGroupId": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "(Required) The security group ID.",
      "allowedPattern": "^(sg-)([0-9a-f]){1,}$"
    },
    "AutomationAssumeRole": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "(Optional) The ARN of the role that allows Automation to perform the actions on your behalf.",
      "default": "",
      "allowedPattern": "^arn:aws(-cn|-us-gov)?:iam::\\d{12}:role\\/[\\w+=,.@_\\/-]+|^$"
    }
  },
  "mainSteps": [
    {
      "name": "ModifySecurityGroup",
      "action": "aws:executeScript",
      "onFailure": "Abort",
      "isCritical": true,
      "isEnd": true,
      "timeoutSeconds": 600,
      "description": "## ModifySecurityGroup\nAdds a new rule to the security group allowing all traffic (0.0.0.0/0).\n## Inputs\n* SecurityGroupId: The security group ID.\n## Outputs\nThis step has no outputs.\n",
      "inputs": {
        "Runtime": "python3.7",
        "Handler": "modify_security_group_handler",
        "InputPayload": {
          "SecurityGroupId": "{{SecurityGroupId}}"
        },
        "Script": "import boto3\n\nec2_resource = boto3.resource(\"ec2\")\nec2_client = boto3.client(\"ec2\")\n\ndef modify_security_group_handler(event, context):\n    sg_id = event[\"SecurityGroupId\"]\n    sg_resource = ec2_resource.SecurityGroup(sg_id)\n    successful = True\n    errorMsg = \"\"\n    //more code
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You would have to use the correct syntax so the `templatefile` function can fill in the details, but not sure if this will work as expected. You could try doing `"SecurityGroupId": "${SecurityGroupId}"` to see what happens.

Comment: I have changed the variables in the ymal file as Marko E suggested, after the change still the error but there is a new function in the automation document, where I can see the steps details, in the input part i can see the values:
{
"SecurityGroupId": "sg-0xxxxxxxxx
"SNSTopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:xxxxxxxxx
}

Script part:
import boto3
ec2_resource = boto3. resource("ec2" )
ec2_client = boto3.client ("ec2")

def modify_security_group_handler(event, context):
sg_id = event ["SecurityGroupId" ]
sns_topic_arn = event.get ("SNSTopicArn" )

Comment: Is the error the same or different this time?

Comment: The error is the same, The supplied parameters for invoking the specified Automation document are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with `templatefile` it is always best to start small...
and yes locals work fine, that should not be a problem, but your variable interpolation is not.

- You have `{{SecurityGroupId}}` that should be `${SecurityGroupId}`
- I do not see you using the `AutomationAssumeRole` maybe that is not needed

---

Here is a small example:

```hcl
locals {
  tests = {
    aaa = { one = "111", two = "222" }
    bbb = { one = "777", two = "999" }
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "test" {
  for_each = local.tests
  triggers = {
    txt = templatefile("./foo.tftpl", { name = each.key, config = each.value })
  }
}
```

the contents of `foo.tftpl`:

```txt
hello ${name}
option one ${config.one}
option two ${config.two}
```

---

and a Terraform plan on that will output:

```txt
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.test["aaa"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "test" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "txt" = <<-EOT
                hello aaa
                option one 111
                option two 222
            EOT
        }
    }

  # null_resource.test["bbb"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "test" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "txt" = <<-EOT
                hello bbb
                option one 777
                option two 999
            EOT
        }
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Always double check the plan! Make sure it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have changed the variable interpolation as you mentioned in your comment. However, the error persists in the automation input. I can see that the values of the variables are passed correctly.
`{
"SecurityGroupId": "sg-0xxxxxxxxx"
"SNSTopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:xxxxxxxx"
}`

`import boto3

ec2_resource = boto3.resource("ec2")
ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2")

def modify_security_group_handler(event, context):
    sg_id = event["SecurityGroupId"]
    sns_topic_arn = event.get("SNSTopicArn")`